# Array, Object, Memory. Actionscript

Tags: arrays, object, memory, actionscript

I have a question related to memory. I will give an example to make it clear how everything works now.

I have 2 arrays:

```
var ArrayNew:Array = new Array();
var ArrayOld:Array = new Array();
```

Also i have a class to store my objects (3 properties). For example:

```
public Id {get; set;}
public Name {get; set;}
public Type {get; set;}
```

The thing is, that i'm filling the ArrayNew with new objects every (for example 12 hours):

```
ArrayNew.push(x, x, x)
.....
ArrayNew.push(x, x, x)
```

It may be about ~200 records or even more.
After that i make this:

```
ArrayOld = ArrayNew;
ArrayNew = null;
```

So the thing is, how memory works in this situation and what happens with objects? Does ArrayOld = ArrayNew make a copy of objects (cause now it works)? Does ArrayNew=null delete created objects? 
I wish you undearstand the situation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects stored in arrayOld get garbage collected if there are no other references to them. The ones from arrayNew are not copied - they are referenced by arrayOld after the assignment.

It's to say that that after:

```
arrayNew[0].name = 'a random silly text';
arrayOld = arrayNew;
arrayOld[0].name = 'another silly string';
trace(arrayNew[0]);
```

You'd get:

```
another silly string
```

*Style note:* Normally you don't start variable/object names with capitals, it's reserved for classes.

Comment: I know. I jsut wrote as the example. Didn't event noticed that i started with Capitals :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to know what happened to ArrayOld.

My code:

```html
var arr_1:Array = ["Hello world!"];
var arr_2:Array = ["My name is Stas!"];

arr_2 = arr_1;
arr_1 = null;

trace(arr_2);// Hello world!
```

If I made a mistake with the understanding of the issue do explain it properly.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayOld = ArrayNew` is simply making `ArrayOld` reference the same thing as `ArrayNew` at that point. The actual data in memory is not copied.

`ArrayNew = null` is simply assigning null value to the `ArrayNew` reference. It doesn't delete the data `ArrayNew` previously referenced, nor does it affect other references to that data (such as `ArrayOld`).

At this point, the original data that `ArrayNew` used to reference has not changed in any way, you've just handed off what variable refers to it.

At this point if you did `ArrayOld = null`, then the original data in memory no longer has any reference to it and it will eventually be purged by garbage collection, but not right away. It will happen "later" at a time the runtime decides is convenient.